# Tree structure in a SPA web app

Tags: single-page-application, hottowel

I'm starting a single page app and still haven't chosen any framework. The only complex thing it needs to do is allow the users to select an element from a tree structure for one of the fields of a form. It would be nice if it worked with both mouse selection and keyboard autocomplete. The tree is 5 levels deep and contains around 500 elements. What would be a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle to show you how to recursively build a tree: http://jsfiddle.net/KtbXb/ .

As far as input, binding a click function to each node will call a function with access to all data associated with clicked node:

```
view:
<li data-bind="text: name, click: yourFunction"></li>

viewmodel: 
var yourFunction = function (data) {
//your function will have access to the node via data
};
```

For keyboard input, you can add an input to your view and bind the value to an observable value. From there, you can probably find a substring search algo online, or even a plugin (jquery.table-filter does a good job of this)